# Why is Django adding a typo when saving a file?

Tags: python, django

I am writing some test code for a project I am making with Django. The test code is such:

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.core.files import File
import sys
import os

from .models import Manual

@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=os.getcwd()+'/temp/django_test')

# Create your tests here.
class ManualModelTests(TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        try:
            os.remove('/temp/django_test/test_image.jpg')
        except FileNotFoundError: 
            pass

    def test_normal_manual_upload(self):
        in_image = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_image.jpg'), 'r+b')
        in_file = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test_manual.pdf'), 'r+b')





        thumbnail = File(in_image)
        in_manual = File(in_file)

        new_manual = Manual.objects.create(
            photo=thumbnail, 
            manual=in_manual, 
            make='yoshimura', 
            model='001', 
            year_min=2007, 
            year_max=2010
        )

        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists('/temp/django_test/photos/test_image.jpg'))
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists     
 ('/temp/django_test/manuals/test_manual.pdf'))

        self.tearDown()
```

The model code is such:

```
class Manual(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos")
    make = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manual = models.FileField(upload_to="manuals")
    year_min = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    year_max = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

The test code aims to create a Manual object (just testing to see if the model saves normally). Upon running the code however, after finishing the model constructor call, I get a crazy long error that comes after many calls of python's makdirs() function ends with

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Jason\\Projects\\motomanuals\\temp\\django_test\\photos\\C:'
```

A full pastebin of the error can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/qWfVdv9L)

My guess is the problems stems from the path ending in '\\C:'?

My questions are:

1. Is my guess right. If not, then why am I getting this error?
2. Why is Django trying to add '\\C:\' to the file path and how do I fix this?

Comment: I think you're on Windows but your code uses Linux-style file paths

Comment: I am on windows, but my paths should be correct because I'm using os.path no?

Comment: How's `MEDIA_ROOT` defined?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT is defined as such:   MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'